# Star Trek: Enterprise - Episode Carbon Creek, song ID

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, production

In the episode *Carbon Creek* of *Star Trek: Enterprise,* T'pol's great-grandmother T'Mir crash lands with several other Vulcans outside a town named Carbon Creek, Pennsylvania—hence the name of the episode.

T'Mir and another surviving Vulcan Mestral enter a tavern called the Pine Tree Bar & Grill. At about ten minutes into the episode, while in the bar, a song plays on the radio or jukebox. It fades in and out. What's the name of the song and who wrote it? Was it written for the show? It feels appropriate to the period and locale, but I didn't hear enough to identify it

Comment: [Crazy Arms](http://www.metrolyrics.com/crazy-arms-lyrics-ray-price.html). Songwriters Chuck Seals, Ralph Eugene Mooney. (Looked up what season and episode, got the DVD out and scanned to around 10:23).

Comment: [Carbon Creek](http://startreksoundtracks.com/episodes/ent/ent-2.html "Carbon Creek") Star Trek Enterprise Season 2 Episode 2 sound tracks. Not written for the show, it's been performed by lots of artists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Crazy Arms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Arms), performed by Ray Price.

[Written in 1956](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Crazy_Arms) by Ralph Mooney and Charles Seals the song is, ironically, about a man whose wife has left him due to his excessive drinking.

Answer (score 3):

*Crazy Arms* was replaced by CBS in 2011 when the episode was being remastered for Blu-ray and international distribution. Not sure why.

My song, *[Gently Falls](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/gently-falls/629074200?i=629074265)*, was the song selected to replace Crazy Arms. If you have Amazon or Netflix, or HULU you can hear it at the same 10:30 time stamp in the show. To hear the song separately use the link below.

My quartery BMI royalty reports show some 40-50,000 views on those sites each 3 months. I am so thankful to have one of my songs be part of the Star Trek Universe!

Comment: Great to hear from you, Dave and thanks for the info. I didn't know it had been changed!

Comment: That's Pretty cool to be on the short list of vocalists who have had their music featured on Star Trek. Well done, Dave!  I am also trying to identify the song played in this episode immediately after "Gently Falls" (at least on my Netflix version). I tried to Shazam it but in that scene the app can't seem to home in on the background music due to the much louder dialogue. If anyone has any clues, it's much appreciated.